# how to convert the given string to array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have the following Strings. I want them to convert into Arrays like below in rails

`"[\"Winter\", \"Summer\", \"Spring\"]"` to `["Winter", "Summer", "Spring"]`

`"[\"IELTS\", \"GRE\", \"PTE\", \"SAT\"]"` to `["IELTS", "GRE", "PTE", "SAT"]`

How can i convert these

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Where do those strings come from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455177/how-to-parse-output-of-array-inspect-back-into-an-array

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with JSON.

```
require 'json'

string = "[\"Winter\", \"Summer\", \"Spring\"]"
JSON.parse(string)
=> ["Winter", "Summer", "Spring"]
```

Answer (score 1):

just alternate solution (not safe) :

```
> string = "[\"Winter\", \"Summer\", \"Spring\"]"
> eval(string)
#=> ["Winter", "Summer", "Spring"]
```

Note: better option to parse with JSON

Comment: **Please, never do things like this in production code**. It may lead to a serious vulnerability.